# Flutter remove space above AppBar for iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The AppBar in iOS has an extra space above, and so the icon doesn't look like it's aligned vertically, how do you remove the extra space above? Thanks! Please refer to screenshots below:

Code:

```html
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
       toolbarHeight: 70,
       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
       title: SvgPicture.asset(
          Assets.mainLogo,
          width: 7.w,
       ),
       centerTitle: true,
    ),
);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just remove `toolbarHeight:70` this line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html)

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0), // here the desired height
          child: AppBar(
            // ...
          )
        ),
```